# Unable to render plotly graph to template in django

Tags: python, django, plotly

I am trying to plot a plotly graph to my django template but unable to do so, getting a blank template.

#### views.py

```
#plotly libraries used
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.offline as py

def home(request):
    df=index(request) #returns a dataframe
    #overall cases
    total_df = df.groupby(['Country'])['Total Cases'].sum()
    total_df = total_df.reset_index()
    fig0 = px.scatter_geo(total_df,locations="Country", locationmode='country names', 
                          color="Total Cases", size='Total Cases',hover_name="Country",
                          projection="orthographic",color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.deep,
                          )
    fig0 = go.Figure(data=fig0)
    plot_div0 = py.plot(fig0, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div',config={'displayModeBar': False})
    
    return render(request, 'test/welcome.html', {'plot_div0':plot_div0})
```

#### welcome.html

```
{{ plot_div0 | safe }}
```